# Не срабатывает задержка

Tags: javascript

```
rotate.onclick = function () {
   setTimeout(clickC(rotate),5000);
};
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { clickC(rotate); },5000);`

Comment: а чего не ответом?

Comment: `setTimeout(clickC, 5000, rotate);` ie10+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код не срабатывает по той причине, что первым аргументом в `setTimeout` Вы передаете ***результат вызова*** функции `clickC(rotate)`.

Правильной записью данного выражения будет

```
rotate.onclick = function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    clickC(rotate);
  }, 5000);
};
```

или

```
rotate.onclick = () => setTimeout(() => { clickC(rotate); }, 5000);
```

---

### Немного теории

У методов `setTimeout` и `setInterval` есть две формы вызова, которые различаются типом и количеством аргументов:

1. Первый аргумент - строка, содержащая код.
   Второй - значение задержки в миллисекундах.

   ```js
       alert('Через 3 секунды будет показано сообщение'); 
       setTimeout("alert('Привет!');", 3000);
   ```

*Такая форма вызова выглядит проще, но она **не рекомендуется**, по тем же причинам что и использование `eval`: это медленнее, и это может быть небезопасно.*

---

2. Первый аргумент - callback-функция.
   Второй - значение задержки в миллисекундах.
   Третий и последующие - параметры, которые будут переданы аргументами в callback-функцию.

```js
let rotate = document.getElementById('rotate'); 
rotate.style.transform = 'skewX(-5deg) rotate(0deg)'; 

rotate.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // таймаут с вызовом ф-ции clickC, и передачей ей трех аргументов
  setTimeout(clickC, 1000, rotate, -180, 180); 
});


clickC(rotate, 0, 0); 
console.log('Клик по центрованному элементу установит таймаут вызова clickC(rotate, -180, 180)'); 

function clickC(el, skInc, rtInc) {
  el.style.transform = el.style.transform.replace(
    /^skewX\((.+)deg\)\s+rotate\((.+)deg\)$/i,
    (s, m1, m2) => `skewX(${+m1 + skInc}deg) rotate(${+m2 + rtInc}deg)`
  ); 
  el.textContent = el.style.transform; 
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  justify-content: center; 
  height: calc(100vh - 3em); 
}

#rotate {
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
  text-align: center; 
  font: 24px sans-serif; 
  cursor: pointer; user-select: none; 
  transition: transform 0.8s linear; 
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate"></div>
```